# building constructors with new variables in java

Tags: java, constructor

I was asked to write a class called `BusArrival`, while `BusArrival` has only one private instance - `Time1 _arrivalTime`. (which is a class wrote, but it's not what my question is about).

Then I needed to call for a constructor in `BusArrival`.

```
private Time1 _arrivalTime;

public BusArrival(int h, int m ,int s) {
    if (h < 23 && h > 0)
        h = h;
    else 
        h = DEFAULT_HOUR;

    if (m < 60 && m > 0) 
        m = m;
    else 
        m = DEFAULT_MINUTE;

    if (s < 60 && s > 0)
        s = s;
    else 
        s = DEFAULT_SECOND;
}
```

but when I do that h, m and s are always returning as 0. if I do the same using Time1 h, s and m it's working fine.

How do I use variables in constructors that I don't already have defined?

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to preserve h, m, s for the object you create declare as private members too, and instead of writing

```
h = h;
```

write

```
this.h = h;
```

add the following declarations:

```
private int h, m, s;
```

Comment: thank you, but it's brings me to a compilation error - "cannot find variable h".

Comment: @Gnoam edited my ans, add the variable as members too.

Comment: I would have done that, but I'm not allowed to add new declarations. both the signature of the constructor and the variables have to stay the same as written.

Comment: @Gnoam then create another class in same package, declare h, m and s as members there and create an object instance for that class say named as myobj and then access as myobj.h = h; and so on

Comment: I have on Time1 varibales called _hour, but in the constructor i declered `_hour = h` as well as i wrote get methodes. `getHour`, getMinute etc. How can I use that? I'm not sure I understood.